# In loopback-component-passport, why is email appended by @loopback instead of setting correct email received from auth callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

In lib/models/user-identity.js

```
   function profileToUser(provider, profile, options) {
  // Let's create a user for that
    var  email = (profile.username || profile.id) + '@loopback.' +
              (profile.provider || provider) + '.com';
```

vs

```
function profileToUser(provider, profile, options) {
  // Let's create a user for that
    var  email = profile.emails[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your own function to replace the defalt profileToUser function. Not sure it's the best practice, but I couldn't think of a better one.

```
var options = {...} // place your profileToUser function here.
passportConfigurator.configureProvider(providerName, options);
```

Comment: 'options' variable is not referenced to set email property in any case. To clarify Question is why A vs B approach and not looking to know work around.